# Same period last year. Leap year

Tags: powerpivot, dax, ssas-tabular

I have 3 columns in my SSAS tabular model: Date, Amount, Amount n-1

The problem is that I would like to have for example a row with:

```
Date           Amount     Amount n-1
29thFeb          0          2000$
```

is there any way to deal with leap years situations? As 29th Feb 2017 does not exist, this row does not show up in my table.

My datasource is just a simple SQL Server Sales Table with 2 columns, Date and Amount

Example of what I would like to achieve when using Date, Amount and Amount(n-1) in a PivotTable, using my SSAS tabular model as datasource:

```
Date           Amount     Amount n-1
1stFeb          1500$       1700$
2ndFeb          1300$       1000$
...
28thFeb         700$        800$    
29thFeb          0          2000$

TOTAL         3500$         5500$
```

Comment: I'm not understanding why you want to display data for a date that doesn't exist?  2/29/2016, a true leap year would be just fine using a standard date table dimension.

Comment: As the report I'm creating has Sales of current and last year, **and** there is a Total Sales Amount at the end of the report. If I don't consider 29th Feb 2016, the Total Sales Amount for last year will be wrong. Also The user wishes to have the report as I stated in my original question.

Comment: @JackCasas, You're right, **29/02/2017** won't appear in your table but **29/02/2016** will do, What is the aggregation you want to perform between both years values? A reproducible example would be useful in order to provide an answer.

Comment: added an example. The aggregation is a simple SUM of the monthly sale.